# Trying to find a book about a kid who ends up being summoned as a demon

Tags: story-identification

I´m trying to find a book about a kid who tries a drug, ends up in an out of body experience, and his soul then gets summoned against his will to serve as a demon by a wizard. 
At first they think he is a low leveled demon but he tries to escape and fighting back, and they then think he is a high ranking demon instead.... Thus he ends up looking like a huge demon.
I remember the book cover looked like a giant minotaur stepping through a portal (Made in poor CG) but I can´t remember the name of the book or who it was made by.

any help would be appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Not what you are looking for, but Pratchett's *Eric* has Rincewind stuck in a similar predicament. And a parrot.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Will definetly look that book up aswell. here´s to hoping someone else might recognize the book i´m after. it felt unfinished storywise and I feel like there might be a sequel or two.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The book I searched for ended up being called *[Into the Abyss](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/21846804-into-the-abyss)* By J.L. Langland and is the first book in his series called "[The Demons of Astlan](https://www.goodreads.com/series/136906-demons-of-astlan)". Thank you all for helping out and even referring me towards similar books in the future.

> Turns out: "The Demon Weed" really is a Gateway Drug!
>
> Who knew?
>
> Tom Perkinje certainly didn't. He had never smoked anything in his life, but as the new kid in town trying to make friends, he'd gone to a party and had foolishly let his new buddy Reggie talk him into trying a joint that he'd picked up from a new dealer.
>
> Before he knew it, Tom was having a seriously bad trip; a total out of body experience where the world had dissolved around him. A few puffs in and he'd gotten this massive case of tunnel vision where the entire party seemed to be happening at the other end of a long tunnel; soon it was like he was having this weird out of body experience looking down at himself.
>
> The next thing Tom knew, there were these deranged myopic wizards from some place called Astlan calling on him in some sort of pig Latin mumbo jumbo. They had somehow mistaken Tom for a demon! He tried to flee but the wizards were relentless and were determined to conjure him into their world and bind him as their demon slave for all of eternity!
>
> Oh, yeah, and those crazy wizards? Turns out they were going to war and planned to use their new demon slave as a secret weapon to obliterate the enemy!